# How to convert string to hyperlink in data table column

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

How do you convert string to hyperlink in data table column? It is not working for the url. Please assist. It is coded using c# in visual studio. I added data table.

```
try
{
    DataTable result = new DataTable();
    result.TableName = "Result";
    result.Columns.Add("Title");
    result.Columns.Add("Name");
    result.Columns.Add("Content");
    result.Columns.Add("Link");

    foreach (SPListItem objSSListItem in objSSList.Items)
    {
        String title = objSSListItem["Title"].ToString();
        String name = objSSListItem["Name"].ToString();
        String content = objSSListItem["Content Type"].ToString();

        if (title.ToUpper().Contains(searchWord.ToUpper()) || name.ToUpper().Contains(searchWord.ToUpper()) || content.ToUpper().Contains(searchWord.ToUpper()))

            intMemberIndex = objSSListItem.ID;
            String url = "http://xxx" + objSSListItem.Url;

            documentLink.NavigateUrl = url;
            HyperLink hl = new HyperLink();

            result.Rows.Add(title, name, content,url);
        }
    }
    FillResultsGrid(result);

}
```

Comment: I don't think adding "urgent" to the title really makes you get BETTER answers any sooner. I think....

Comment: You're not showing your final output to the GridView, or whatever FillResultsGrid is doing.

Comment: Nor are you doing anything with the hyperlink object you create, which you don't assign any values to